# Accelerated C++: compiling the programs in chapter 4

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I wrote a Makefile to compile the files and output the file "main", which I will eventually execute by "./main". Below is my Makefile:

```
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic
BIN=prog

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: Student_info median grade main

main: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main grade.o median.o Student_info.o

grade: grade.h grade.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) grade.cpp -o grade.o

median: median.h median.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) median.cpp -o median.o

Student_info: Student_info.h Student_info.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Student_info.cpp -o Student_info.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f main
```

However, it says

```
clang++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic Student_info.cpp -o Student_info.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Student_info] Error 1
```

What is wrong with my Makefile?

Comment: To output object files, use `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Student_info: Student_info.h Student_info.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Student_info.cpp -o Student_info.o
```

Looks like you want this to compile to an object file - without linking. To do this, you need to pass `-c`. Also, the name of the target should be `Student_info.o`:

```
Student_info.o: Student_info.h Student_info.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c Student_info.cpp -o Student_info.o
```

Ditto for `grade` and `median`.

`main` should depend on not only `main.cpp` but also the object files you are linking it with:

```
main: main.cpp Student_info.o grade.o median.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main grade.o median.o Student_info.o
```